# PrepareResponse().AsActionResult() throws unsupported exception DotNetOpenAuth CTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0

Currently I'm developing an OAuth2 authorization server using DotNetOpenAuth CTP version. My authorization server is in asp.net MVC3, and it's based on the sample provided by the library. Everything works fine until the app reaches the point where the user authorizes the consumer client.

There's an action inside my OAuth controller  which takes care of the authorization process, and is very similar to the equivalent action in the sample:

```
[Authorize, HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AuthorizeResponse(bool isApproved)
    {
        var pendingRequest = this.authorizationServer.ReadAuthorizationRequest();

        if (pendingRequest == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Missing authorization request.");
        }

        IDirectedProtocolMessage response;
        if (isApproved)
        {
            var client = MvcApplication.DataContext.Clients.First(c => c.ClientIdentifier == pendingRequest.ClientIdentifier);
            client.ClientAuthorizations.Add(
                new ClientAuthorization
                {
                    Scope = OAuthUtilities.JoinScopes(pendingRequest.Scope),
                    User = MvcApplication.LoggedInUser,
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                });
            MvcApplication.DataContext.SaveChanges();
            response = this.authorizationServer.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(pendingRequest, User.Identity.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            response = this.authorizationServer.PrepareRejectAuthorizationRequest(pendingRequest);
        }

        return this.authorizationServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(response).AsActionResult();
    }
```

Everytime the program reaches this line:

```
this.authorizationServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(response).AsActionResult();
```

The system throws an exception which I have researched with no success. The exception is the following:
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

The stack trace: http://pastebin.com/TibCax2t

The only thing I've done differently from the sample is that I used entity framework's code first approach, an I think the sample was done using a designer which autogenerated the entities.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you started from the example, the problem Andrew is talking about stays in `DatabaseKeyNonceStore.cs`. The exception is raised by one on these two methods:

```
    public CryptoKey GetKey(string bucket, string handle) {
        // It is critical that this lookup be case-sensitive, which can only be configured at the database.
        var matches = from key in MvcApplication.DataContext.SymmetricCryptoKeys
                      where key.Bucket == bucket && key.Handle == handle
                      select new CryptoKey(key.Secret, key.ExpiresUtc.AsUtc());

        return matches.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, CryptoKey>> GetKeys(string bucket) {
        return from key in MvcApplication.DataContext.SymmetricCryptoKeys
               where key.Bucket == bucket
               orderby key.ExpiresUtc descending
               select new KeyValuePair<string, CryptoKey>(key.Handle, new CryptoKey(key.Secret, key.ExpiresUtc.AsUtc()));
    }
```

I've resolved moving initializations outside of the query:

```
    public CryptoKey GetKey(string bucket, string handle) {
        // It is critical that this lookup be case-sensitive, which can only be configured at the database.
        var matches = from key in db.SymmetricCryptoKeys
                      where key.Bucket == bucket && key.Handle == handle
                      select key;

        var match = matches.FirstOrDefault();

        CryptoKey ck = new CryptoKey(match.Secret, match.ExpiresUtc.AsUtc());

        return ck;
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, CryptoKey>> GetKeys(string bucket) {
        var matches = from key in db.SymmetricCryptoKeys
               where key.Bucket == bucket
               orderby key.ExpiresUtc descending
               select key;

        List<KeyValuePair<string, CryptoKey>> en = new List<KeyValuePair<string, CryptoKey>>();

        foreach (var key in matches)
            en.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, CryptoKey>(key.Handle, new CryptoKey(key.Secret, key.ExpiresUtc.AsUtc())));

        return en.AsEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,CryptoKey>>();
    }
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `ICryptoKeyStore` implementation may be attempting to store `CryptoKey` directly, but it's not a class that is compatible with the Entity framework (due to not have a public default constructor).  Instead, define your own entity class for storing the data in `CryptoKey` and your `ICryptoKeyStore` is responsible to transition between the two data types for persistence and retrieval.